# Can't create bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im having a really odd error here...

Today I wanted to setup a new bot project but im having so much trouble!

Running under Ubuntu 18.04 if that makes any difference. Here's exactly what I did:

```
npm init #I follow the steps and all
npm install discord.js
npm install nodemon
touch index.js

#I start the bot
nodemon index.js
```

From there, i'll get an error basically telling me that index.js is empty. So, I add in the following code in it:

```
const discord = require("discord.js"); //import discord
var client = new discord.Client();

//console.log(client.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === "pkachu").id);

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("ready to kick ass");
});

client.login('VALID discord token thing');
```

Sadly, i'll get the following error:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
(node:9771) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at WebSocketManager.connect (/home/lolcat/Documents/goodbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:135:26)
    at Client.login (/home/lolcat/Documents/goodbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:220:21)
(node:9771) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9771) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Okay, so this thing is telling me that it has an invalid discord.js token. Alright, maybe it changed or something. Thing is, it didn't change. In fact, that token appears to still be valid and make one of my older bots work!

I've tried everything at this point. I also tried following the link it gave me but to no avail, it still "crashes".

Any tips?

Comment: My project is put to a halt cause of this, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Make sure you are using an actual bot token and not a Client ID or Client Secret from the Developer Portal.

Comment: @Tarazed i am using a client ID... Tho, in my older project, using a client ID works just fine!

Comment: I'd be surprised if that was the case, client ID shouldn't work. You need to create a bot within your application on the portal and then use it's token.

Comment: @Tarazed ask the people on .gg/apandah, I really did manage to create a selfbot using the API..

Comment: @Tarazed the reason i want to create a selfbot is because normal bots cannot use the "go live" feature...

Comment: That's fine.  I'm unwilling to help break Discords TOS though.  Perhaps someone else can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you guys think you can get away with selfbots, no you can't. :kek: